# Disable automatically hiding scrollbars in Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: windows-10, registry, scrollbar, accessibility, windows-10-iot-core

In Windows 10 there is an option to "Automatically hide scroll bars in Windows" that can be set to Off:

[image: Screenshot: Automatically hide scroll bars in Windows]

It's controlled by the following registry entry:

```
Location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility
Name: DynamicScrollbars
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0x00000000
```

I have tried adding this registry entry in Windows 10 IoT Core using PowerShell with these commands:

```
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel" -Name "Accessibility"
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility" -Name "DynamicScrollbars" -Value "0x00000000" -PropertyType "DWord"
```

But scrollbars do not seem to be affected by this registry entry on this OS. Is there any way to set this preference?

Comment: I'm confirming if the registry entry supports on Windows IoT Core with related team. Appreciate for your patience.

Comment: Please try with my following response. If there is any problem, feel free let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late response.The registry key seems to be working for me just fine but you need to add the registry key with **DefaultAccount**. Otherwise **HKCU** will be the administrator and that will not have an effect on the UI.

In addition, if the **VerticalScrollBarVisibility** property of ScrollViewer is “Visible” then the registry setting of 0 will force the scroll bar to appear regardless of whether there is sufficient content to scroll the UI.  A registry setting of 1 will keep the scroll bar hidden until there is sufficient content.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="…
```

If the property is “Auto” then the registry setting of 0 will only show the full scroll bar when there is enough content to display the scroll bar.  When the registry setting is 1, the scroll bar will appear thin when there is enough content, or hidden if no content.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="…
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! Adding the registry key to the DefaultAccount registry path worked: Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2702878673-795188819-444038987-503\Control Panel\Accessibility